# WPF TabControl - In need of a default message before tabs load

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabs, wpf-controls

I have a WPF TabControl who's TabItems are MEF'd in at run time. However, they are MEF'd in only when a certain item in a left-hand treeview is selected. What I'd like to do is display a centered message inside the TabControl indicating "No Active Scenario Selected". I tried adding a TextBlock inside the TabControl but what I got was a TabItem instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is simply by putting a `TextBlock` on top of the `TabControl` and show it when the `TabControl` doesn't have any Tabs added.

You can bind the `Visibility` of the `TextBlock` to the `HasItems` property of the `TabControl` and use a value converter ([BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms609059%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or your own implementation) to show and hide the `TextBlock`.